# JQ with shell to get JSON array dont return in one item for value with spaces

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I am using MacOS JQ tool to get JSON array parsed using Shell script that is retuned via API hence i cant modify the JSON value from Key with any """" and \ or in. The <filename.json> | JQ .[] command returns the array split into multiple items rather one for one "Value". How to write JQ Command to ensure that the returned parse value including special character, whitespace is not trimmed or splitted to new item of array.

**Sample API response and not local file that I can edit.**

```json
{
   "location_preview":"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png",
   "location_name":"Full Back",
   "location_art":"EQWEQW wqeqweqwe @#@!#!@# qweqwewqe",
   "location_preview_1":"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
}{
   "location_preview":"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png",
   "location_name":"Full Back",
   "location_art":"This is space string",
   "location_preview_1":"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
}{
   "location_preview":"http://yrtrtytry.com/link_to_your_preview.png",
   "location_name":"Full Back",
   "location_art":" http://ytyrtytry.com/link_to_your_artwork.png",
   "location_preview_1":"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
}{
   "location_preview":"http://eqweqw.com/link_to_your_preview.png",
   "location_name":"Full Back",
   "location_art":" http://weqweqw.com/link_to_your_artwork.png",
   "location_preview_1":"http://weqweqw.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
}
```

When I return the element and want to loop using for loop the item with space value in the key will go into different array item and not as one string with spaces.

Example:  for "location_art":"This is space string" --> The value is getting split which I don't want. How to fix this issue.

My code snippet:

```sh
newValue=$(cat response_1.json | jq '.order_items[].print_locations[].location_art')

for item in $newValue;
do
    echo "New value 2: " ${item}
done
```

```
New value 2:  http://weqweqw.com/link_to_your_artwork.png"
New value 2:  "
New value 2:  http://sdasdassd.com/link_to_your_artwork.png"
New value 2:  "
New value 2:  http://dasdas.com/link_to_your_artwork.png"
New value 2:  "EQWEQW
New value 2:  wqeqweqwe
New value 2:  @#@!#!@#
New value 2:  qweqwewqe"
New value 2:  "EQWEQW
New value 2:  wqeqweqwe
New value 2:  @#@!#!@#
New value 2:  qweqwewqe"
```

Comment: Please consider using triple-backtick fences to start and end code formatting sections -- unlike the older four-space method, this lets you tell SO which kind of syntax highlighting to use for each section.

Comment: Beyond that, `for item in $anything` is always a bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `jq`, it's a problem with using unquoted expansions (of which your code currently contains several). You'd have it with *any* input source.

### When you want to store a list of items, store them in an array.

Targeting modern bash (4.0+):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0123].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

mapfile -t newValue < <(
  jq -r '.order_items[].print_locations[].location_art' response_1.json
)

for item in "${newValue[@]}"; do
    echo "New value 2: ${item}"
done
```

---

Targeting legacy bash (including 3.2), and taking advantage of better error handling available with `read -a`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || { echo "ERROR: bash required" >&2; exit 1; }

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a newValue < <(
  jq -r '.order_items[].print_locations[].location_art' response_1.json \
    && printf '\0'
) || { echo "jq failed; aborting" >&2; exit 1; }

for item in "${newValue[@]}"; do
    echo "New value 2: ${item}"
done
```

Comment: Hi Charles thanks for the reply, can you help to share the read array similar reply as my machine wont go internet and not all developers have bash 4.0 , would be great help

Comment: @VickyDhas, I edited in full examples of both approaches.

Comment: You saved my day, just one last query as i am not expert win Shell , if there is a Curl response json returned like "projectResponse=$(curl -u "$username:$password" "https://bitbucket.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/")" - I am first doing this response to store in json file for records so above is now working, how to pass the response directly to the IFS code above instead of file.